# Python how to add quote to one of the element in a list?

Tags: python, string

`values` is a list looks like `['13020638659', '711799502', '4681912759', '07/21/2021']`

I'd like to connect all of its elements to create a `value_str` look like this

`(13020638659, 711799502, 4681912759, '07/21/2021')`

This is what I do `values_str = "(%s)" % (', '.join( values ))`

But the output would be `(13020638659, 711799502, 4681912759, 07/21/2021)`

There are no quotes for the datatime string. How can I add quotes on it?

Comment: Is it always the 4th element of the list?

Comment: Your required *value_str* appears to be a tuple. Is that what you intend?

Comment: @Barmar In this case it is. But I have other datasets, which might not be. So I want a more general solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use different code to format the date than the numbers, so you can add quotes around it.

```
values_str = f"({', '.join(values[:-1])}, '{values[-1]}')"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the value consists of something else than digits with `str.isdigit()`:

```
"({})".format(", ".join(v if v.isdigit() else f"'{v}'" for v in values))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can attempt to convert strings to integer:

```
def get_repr(x):
    try:
        return repr(int(x))
    except ValueError:
        return repr(x)

f'({",".join(map(get_repr, values))})'
```